# How to invoke a concrete Scala trait method from Java?

Tags: java, scala, traits

I have a Java / Scala mix Maven project. I need to reuse a Saddle method `make` that is concretely defined as part of a trait called `Index`. The method is defined [here](https://github.com/saddle/saddle/blob/master/saddle-core/src/main/scala/org/saddle/Index.scala#L588) if that helps in any way. I have tried calling that method from java using `Index.make` or `Index$class.make` but in both cases I get the `error: cannot find symbol` compilation error.

Is there a way to call a concrete Trait method from Java?

Comment: Please show the code for your `trait` - I'm assuming that `make` is implemented on the `trait Index`, but it's an assumption and given `Index$class.make` doesn't work could be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `trait` is similar to a Java interface in a sense that it is not a concrete constructor.

From Scala:

```
class IndexImpl extends Index[SomeParamtersHere] {}
val x = new ClassImpl
x.make(..)
```

Or use an object:

```
object Index extends Index {}
Index.make(..)
```

From Java:

Traits with concrete implementations will compile to the appropriate `abstract class`. If certain members don't have concrete implementation, you have to implement them.

```
import org.saddle.Index
public class TraitImpl extends Index$class {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer. Calling it like this works but only because the Index trait already has an Index object available (that I didn't notice before):

```
Index$.MODULE$.make(rrule, startDate, endDate);
```