# How to get the class of a trait within an object defined in scala from within a java class?

Tags: java, scala, object, traits, owner

I have a Scala object similar to the following:

```
object MyConfig {
  @PropertyManagerSources(Array("my.properties"))
  trait MyConfigOwner extends PropertyManagerConfig {
    @Key("my.key")
    def getSomething(): Boolean
}
```

This is using Owner to manage properties.

I am trying to access the trait within a java class like such:

```
import com.bah.cr.common.config.MyConfig.MyConfigOwner;

public class MyJavaClass{
  MyConfigOwner config = PropertyManagerConfig Factory.create(MyConfigOwner.class);
}
```

However, I get the error that MyConfig does not exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356442/how-to-invoke-a-concrete-scala-trait-method-from-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this works.  My issue was an error in the package of the scala class.